# production.ERROR: Undefined variable: id Laravel blade

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I have this code in the controller:

```php
public function appraisal(Request $request)
{
    try {        
        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $userId = Auth::user()->id; 
        $company = OrgCompany::where('id', $userCompany)->first();
        $identities = Identity::where('company_id', $userCompany)->pluck('appraisal_name','id');
        $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userId)
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_approved', 3)->orWhere('is_visible', 0);
            })
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->orderBy('goal_type_id');

        $method = $request->method();

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $id = $request->input('identity_id');
            if ($request->has('search')) {
                // select search
                if ($request->input('identity_id')) {
                    $goals->where('identity_id',$request->input('identity_id'));
                }
                $goals = $goals->get();  
                return view('appraisal-default',['goals' => $goals, 'identities' => $identities]);
            } elseif ($request->has('viewIdentity')) {
                // select goal identity
                if ($request->input('identity_id')) {
                    return view('performance_dashboard', $id);
                }
            }
        } else {
            //select current year
            $goals = $goals->get();               
            return view('appraisal-default',['goals' => $goals, 'identities' => $identities]);
        }
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
        return back();
    }
}
```

view blade: appraisal-default

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <label class="control-label"> Performance Period:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select id="identity" name="identity_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">--- Select Performance Period ---</option>
      @foreach ($identities as $ids => $name)
        <option value="{{ $ids }}" {{ request( 'identity_id')==$ids ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
    <form action="{{ route('performance_dashboard', $id->id) }}" method="get" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" name="viewIdentity"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> View Identity</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the view, I have two buttons with names:  search and viewIdentity

When the

```xml
<select id="identity" name="identity_id" class="form-control">
```

is selected.

If search button is submitted, it displays the result on the same page. This is working.

However, where I'm having problem is when viewIdentity button is submitted. At this point  it suppose to take the id of the dropdown as the parameter in:

```xml
<form action="{{ route('performance_dashboard', $id->id) }}" method="get" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" name="viewIdentity"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> View Identity</button>
</form>
```

and display the result in another page: performance_dashboard

I got this error in the view:

> production.ERROR: Undefined variable: id

It points to this line in the view:

```xml
<form action="{{ route('performance_dashboard', $id->id) }}" method="get" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Look at your code: `return view('appraisal-default',['goals' => $goals, 'identities' => $identities]);`, are you passing `'id' => $id` there? Nope. So you can't use `$id` in your `appraisal-default.blade.php` view.

Comment: How do I pass the id of the dropdown @foreach ($identities as $ids => $name) as the parameter

Comment: You'll have to use JS to alter that URL to the value being selected from the dropdown. Or don't rely on URL parameters generated from a dropdown. If you used a `GET` request, it would show up in the URL as `?id={value-from-dropdown}` as a Query String parameter.